# Find tags based on an attribute value with the highest number

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to find a way to find the `<span>` tag with the highest number in the `data-resolution` attribute value.

This is what I have managed to do so far.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<span data-type="video-src" data-url="https://1080.com" data-resolution="1080"></span>
<span data-type="video-src" data-url="https://720.com" data-resolution="720"></span>
<span data-type="video-src" data-url="https://480.com" data-resolution="480"></span>
<span data-type="video-src" data-url="https://360.com" data-resolution="360"></span>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

x = soup.select('span[data-resolution="1080"]')
print(x)
```

The problem here is that `1080` is a fixed value. I guess I could create a conditional `if` statement with all numbers I assume will be available, but I would rather just pick the highest number.

So how can I make Beautiful Soup look for the the `<span>` tag with the highest number in the `data-resolution` attribute value?

Comment: Are you doing this for a particular website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can narrow down on just the `data-resolution` items and then use `max` on that attribute since each item is essentially a dictionary.

```
def custom_key(css):
    val = css.get("data-resolution", 0)
    return int(val)

max(soup.select('span[data-resolution]'), key=custom_key)
<span data-resolution="1080" data-type="video-src" data-url="https://1080.com"></span>
```

Comment: I am not completely familiar with the get() method. Is there a reason for including the `0`? Perhaps you can add a brief explanation?

Comment: I did it as a fallback in case the value was not present, when you use get instead of normal dictionary bracket methodology it allows you to provide a default value in case that key is not present

Answer (score 1):

There may be better and more succinct ways to do this but here's one idea.

Iterate over all the span elements. Build a tuple comprised of the data-resolution (as an integer) and the entire span element. Append that tuple to a list. Sort the list. Extract the data of interest.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<span data-type="video-src" data-url="https://1080.com" data-resolution="1080"></span>
<span data-type="video-src" data-url="https://720.com" data-resolution="720"></span>
<span data-type="video-src" data-url="https://480.com" data-resolution="480"></span>
<span data-type="video-src" data-url="https://360.com" data-resolution="360"></span>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

spanlist = []
for span in soup.select('span'):
    spanlist.append((int(span['data-resolution']), span))
print(sorted(spanlist)[-1][1])
```

**Output:**

```
<span data-resolution="1080" data-type="video-src" data-url="https://1080.com"></span>
```

Or, if you want something that's hard to understand but functional then:

```
print(max([((int(span['data-resolution']), span)) for span in soup.select('span')])[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Because we all love one-liners:

```py
result = max(soup.select('span[data-resolution]'), key=lambda span: int(span.get('data-resolution')))
```